# How to map survey answers to option numbers using pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dataframe and series like as given below

```
user_response = pd.DataFrame({
'val_string': ['Correct','Mute','Test13','Test15','Unverified',np.nan,'>10 Edu'],
'num':[np.nan,np.nan,1201,1203,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan]
 })

option_numbers = pd.DataFrame({
'answer':['Correct','Incorrect','mute','cannot see','paralysed','illiterate','tired','cannot hear','NIL',
          'English','Malay','Mandarin','Hokkien','Teochew','Cantonese','Other - specify','Chinese',
          '0 Edu','1-6 Edu','7-10 Edu','>10 Edu','Unreachable','Incomplete','Unverified','Complete'],
                             'option':[1,0,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1,2,3,4,5,0,1,2]})
option_number = option_number.set_index('answer')['option']
```

Though I am able to map successfully based on the code below for the matching items, I lose existing values for `non-matching` items

```
user_response['num'] = user_response['val_string'].map(option_numbers)
```

If you run my code, you will see that it loses the value of `Test13`,`Test15` as it is not present in the `option_numbers series` and does not match `Mute` with `mute` due to case-sensitive issue

Can you help me figure out this?

I expect my output to be like as shown below

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need both columns in the data frames to be in lower or upper case

```
user_response['val_string'] = user_response['val_string'].str.lower()
option_numbers['answer'] = option_numbers['answer'].str.lower()
```

then simply use `fillna` to fill in the missing values, you must set the indexes in both data-frames to the correct column for this to work.

```
user_response = user_response.set_index('val_string')
option_numbers = option_numbers.set_index('answer')
user_response['num'] = user_response['num'].fillna(option_numbers['option'])
user_response
val_string
correct          1.0
mute             0.0
test13        1201.0
test15        1203.0
unverified       1.0
NaN              NaN
>10 edu          4.0
Name: num, dtype: float64
```

Comment: I get an error, when I try to assign the output to `user_response['num']` column.

Comment: `ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis`

Comment: you can do this using map `user_response['val_string'].map(option_numbers.set_index('answer')['option'])`

Comment: No this still doesn't work. I mean the code in the comment section still PRODUCES `NA`

Comment: I get this error `KeyError: "None of ['answer'] are in the columns"`

Comment: i believe you are either using a different data-frame than the example, or using the data-frame after performing some operations on it. try doing a new run starting with new data-frames.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201752/discussion-between-sedaradji-and-ssmk).